# Html tag containing a hash being placed randomly throughout the site

Tags: bug, advertising

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48600271/what-is-the-best-program-to-make-so-one-video) question keeps showing a floating hash where an ad should be:

> [image]

And when I peek at the markup, there's a `html` tag in the middle of the page, containing the `#` (Yes, I know, pictures of code are evil. The parent tag is huge though, and I wanted to show that it's just kind of floating there):

> [image]

When I refresh, sometimes it shows the ad, and sometimes it shows the hash. I haven't seen it happen on any other questions.

---

It's on Code Review too:

> [image]

---

It's on Stats now, but between questions:

> [image]

---

This is on Edge. I haven't tested other browsers.

Comment: Someone hook up the devs on a caffeine IV stat. Its been an interesting week for them :(. I can't replicate it on vivaldi so that's a little strange. Might help to include what your browser is? I do suspect the inter-post hash is also where an ad should be.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Added. And it might be an ad on Stats too. I thought I had joined that site, so I wasn't expecting ads, but I might not have.

Comment: I think it is helpful if you can provide either the value of id attribute that sits on that iframe tag or the id of the div that encloses it. I suspect those id's to uniquely identify the ad, making it easier to find the source ad and fix whatever needs fixing. It could also be location dependent so you if you have no problem sharing where you're roughly located (or where you expect your internet connection is located)  I would edit that in as well.

Comment: @rene ok. Unfortunately today I'm working, so I won't be using the full site at all. I'll see tonight.

Comment: Maybe a [new test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190328/empty-advert-box-showing-above-questions)? :)